# Typescript type assertion doesn't work when field object is asserted in the function

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

I'm trying to use a type assertion on a object field in a function and then use the return object (which is asserted in the function).

Here an example:

```
interface MyInterface {
    abc: string;
}

type Abc = "A" | "B";

function assertAbc(v: string): asserts v is Abc {
    if (!["A", "B"].includes(v)) {
        throw Error();
    }
};

const needAbc = (_: Abc) => true;

const shouldBeWithAbcType = () => {
    const myObj: MyInterface = { abc: "A" };

    // Everything that come after this should be an object with abc as type
    assertAbc(myObj.abc);

    // this work as intended, abc is of type Abc
    needAbc(myObj.abc);

    // Return the object
    return myObj;
}

const c = shouldBeWithAbcType();

// c.abc is a string, so this doesn't work, why ?
needAbc(c.abc);
```

Why `needAbc(c.abc)` doesn't work ?

The ts playground with the example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlTk4AjBALmQGcwpQBzAbiIF8iix0AHFAEEqyALzIARIInIAPpIBCE9kRgBXEAjDAA9iHJ060MMIQAKAG60GTEMwCUtOIeN1kF5MDenCJMsBhkMwBCAG0pCQAaRQkAXQA6UAQAGzUAEwg6S3t7XzJ85DAACygdAHdkAFEoUqgze3Z8rg4VBD0GZBAICDSfcTMAfVpTXNEAPkKoNQhW9rB6Ip01ZLSFCAB1YGLTABV%20FH7RieJ8tpAOgFt0AHkKACtaDGxIWEQDwnIqWgjkFr9SZxGKAmKhmK63O7xSgIBr-ZAAenhhSKXmQZR0UAA1nCuj1TGCbvcoVRYfkoBAwGooPpwfd2FwiGcOggxAslis1pttlQ9gJ6uxEcgdii3GkdJkQAByeborHRMpFdDIAD8RFxvVBCGJMPYQA)

The same example but without the object (returning the Abc type) works though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Type Guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards). I think the `asserts` keyword is redundant. Also, a type guard function must return a `boolean` indicating whether the input is of the type you expect or not.

```
function isAbc(v: string): v is Abc {
    if (!["A", "B"].includes(v)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlTk4AjBALmQGcwpQBzAbiIF8iix0AHFAEEqyALzIARIInIAPpIBCE9kRgBXEAjDAA9iHJ060MMIQAKAG60GTEMwCUtOIeN1kF5MDenCJMsBhkMwBCAG0pCQAaRQkAXQA6UAQAGzUAEwg6S3t7XzJ85DAACygdAHdkAFEoUqgze3Z8rg4VdU1tPU86U0trRhZHdy7kH2J8gKCwiOiJJQSk1Iysixy8gtIoCDA1KH14ZKNGsi4-Da2d-UY1CHYThD0GZBAICDSfcTMAfVpTXNEAPkKUGuKnuIEedCKOjUyTSCggAHVgMVTAAVfgoD5-QFjMhgx4AW3QAHkKAArWgYbCQWCITGEchUWgRZAtU4GIxQExUMxE0lk+KUBANdkAelFhSKXmQZR0UAA1uznq8enzyYKqCL8pttrtkGqybduPiwMgEGJ6FCYXDEciimiMfV2OLkKipW40jpMiAAOSm2UK6JlIroZAAfm4EzMXh6CA1wtyuNIyrePLjQpFXCAA)

Comment: The problem is the same with type guards:

Comment: Did you see the playground link? `if (isAbc(c.abc)) {}` works as expected.